# What type of minerals exist in this rock?

Tags: geology

![enter image description here]Arizona desert wash
A very heavy rocking have a few and when busted open beautiful veins of dark silver sometimes yellow gold.light pink and teal looking(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRJgq.jpg)white semi round .very heavy[image][image]

Comment: It looks like quartz

Answer (score 2):

It is massive white quartz also referred to as milky quartz, the streaks are  trace impurities and can occasionally include valuable metals like gold but just as often included fools gold (pyrite).

This chat can help with more detailed identification of trace metals https://www.mindat.org/mesg-11-219962.html

[image]